# Issue when running code from SQL server agent - azure.storage.blob - module azure not found

Tags: python, azure, sql-agent-job

I'm having a problem with some python code that connects to an azure storage container.

Code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import logging
import os, sys

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name = accountName, account_key = accountKey, connection_string=connectionString)

block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(containerName,blob_name=blobName,file_path=fileNameToUpload)
```

Ok, so this code works when executed using a command prompt.

When its executed using a SQL agent job:

> line 1, in       from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

pip list:

```
azure-common         1.1.27
azure-core           1.19.0
azure-storage-blob   1.5.0
azure-storage-common 1.4.2
```

Using python 3.7.4

The credential that I use to run the SQL agent job is mapped to my userid which has admin privileges on the server.

I used [the quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) to get me started.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing an old version of `azure.storage.version` v1.5.0, in the latest version, v12.x.x, you need to use `BlobServiceClient` instead.

```
######################################
pip install azure-storage-blob==12.9.0
######################################

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=url, credential=self._account_key)
```

The link you mentioned it's already pointing to the latest version

Comment: Sorry, this did not work either.
Even though i was using an outdated library, i could still run it using cmd prompt.
THE ISSUE here is that it does not work when running until a SQL Agent process.